# How to call an Abstract class overriden method that has parameters

Tags: java, android, polymorphism, abstraction

I have an interface:

```
public interface ICustomObjectListingViews {
    View createCustomObjectListingView(MyDBObject myDBObject);
}
```

Then :

```
public abstract class AbstractICustomObjectListingViews implements ICustomObjectListingViews {

@Override
    public View createCustomObjectListingView(MyDBObject myDBObject) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I then try to implement the interface by extending the abstract class :

```
public class MyCustomObjectListingView extends AbstractICustomObjectListingViews {

@Override
    public VIew createCustomObjectListingView(MyDBObject myDBObject) {
        Log.v("MyApp", ">>>> " + myDBObject.get_myObjectDescription());

        TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
        textView.setText(myDBObject.get_myObjectDescription());

        return textView;
    }
}
```

I use MyObject to map my database results:

```
public class MyDBObject {
    public MyDBObject() {
    }

    private String _myObjectDescription;

    public void set_myObjectDescription(String _myObjectDescription) {
        this._myObjectDescription = _myObjectDescription;
    }

    public String get_myObjectDescription() {
        return _myObjectDescription;
    }
}
```

I, however, get a null pointer whenever I try to call `MyCustomObjectListingView`'s implementation of  `createCustomObjectListingView(MyDBObject myDBObject)`.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String MyDBObject.get_myObjectDescription()' on a null object reference
```

at :

```
Log.v("MyApp", ">>>> " + myDBObject.get_myObjectDescription());
```

This is how I call it:

```
MyDBObject myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.set_myObjectDescription("HELLO WORLD");

ICustomObjectListingViews iCustomObjectListingViews = new  MyCustomObjectListingView();
iCustomObjectListingViews.createCustomObjectListingView(myObject);
```

What am I getting wrong? How should I call an overriding class' overriden method? How can I make the above attempt work?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: No you don't gets wrong. It's look OK. it's working correctly on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to implement `createCustomObjectListingView(MyDBObject myDBObject)` in `AbstractICustomObjectListingViews` , let implement it directly in the concrete class `MyCustomObjectListingView` (in this way you avoid the `null` return).
Erase the method from `AbstractICustomObjectListingViews`, so that it appears like that

```
   public abstract class AbstractICustomObjectListingViews implements ICustomObjectListingViews {
     //other methods
}
```

and leave `MyCustomObjectListingView` as it is.